# python regular expression doesn't match all letters after "or" group

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match `FD` or `MD` in a string by doing:

```
matches = re.findall(r"(F|M)D",myString)
```

Suppose `myString = 'MD'`. Then, `matches` becomes

```
matches = ['M']
```

Why does it ignore `D`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `(F|M)` is a group, and `D` is not a part of this group.

Use this instead:

```
matches = re.findall(r"((?:F|M)D)",myString)
```

For a visual representation of the differences between these two patterns, I really like to use Regexper.com:

- [`(F|M)D`](https://regexper.com/#%28F%7CM%29D)
- [`((?:F|M)D)`](https://regexper.com/#%28%28%3F%3AF%7CM%29D%29)

The Python documentation on regular expressions has a lot more information available [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping).

Note that `?:` indicates that `F|M` is a "non-capturing" group. If the pattern were `((F|M)D)` instead, then `matches` would be `[('MD', 'M')]` (which doesn't sound like what you want).